# Bubble animation for views in Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

when I launch the screen I need to show the views on the screen using bubble animation like Zoom-in, zoom-out, fade-in etc.

Comment: This may be useful to you. Try the below URL https://github.com/SunnyGarg/Bubble-ProgressBar

Comment: What do you mean by bubble animation? Because fade in/out and zoom in/out have nothing to do with bubbles...

Comment: We are adding some android xml animation to views, like that.